# How to create correct endpoints within an isolated network in Docker, NextJS and Nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, next.js

I have a Docker network that is an isolated network and reverse proxy that serves the NextJS app to the localhost. Unfortunately, fetch to the backend gets failed whenever I open the browser. However, curl http://rustserver-dc:10000/ responds with the data. I do not want the DB and backend to get exposed, only is available from NextJS app when browsing.

Nginx conf:

```
worker_processes 1;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  sendfile on;

  upstream api {
    server nextjs-app:3000;
  }

  server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://api;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
  }
}
```

docker-compose:

```
version: '3.8'

services:

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - rust-server
      - nextjs-app
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - app_network
 

  nextjs-app:
    build: 
      context: ./client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: nextjs-app
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
      - DB_USER=${DB_USER}
      - DB_PASS=${DB_PASS}
    expose:
      - "3000"
    networks:
      - app_network

  rust-server:
    build:
      context: ./userserver
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: rustserver-dc
    expose:
      - "10000"
    networks:
      - app_network
    volumes:
      - './userserver:/usr/src/userserver'
      - '/usr/src/userserver/target'
    environment:
      - MY_LOG_LEVEL=info
      - MY_LOG_STYLE=Always
      - DATABASE_URL=${DATABASE_URL}
      - STRIPE_SECRET_KEY=${STRIPE_SECRET_KEY}
      - STRIPE_PUBLISH_KEY=${STRIPE_PUBLISH_KEY}
      - ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET=${ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET}
      - REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET=${REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET}
      - RESET_PASSWORD_SECRET=${RESET_PASSWORD_SECRET}
      - REDIS_URL=${REDIS_URL}

  surrealdb:
    image: surrealdb/surrealdb
    environment:
      - DB_USER=${DB_USER}
      - DB_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
    expose:
      - "8000"
    networks:
      - app_network
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/surrealdb/data
    command: "start --user ${DB_USER} --pass {DB_PASSWORD} --log full 
file://var/lib/surreal/data"

networks:
  app_network:
    driver: bridge
    

volumes:
  data:
```

Next js index page:

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import axios from 'axios';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function Home() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://rustserver-dc:10000')
      .then(res => {
        setData(res.data);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      })
  }, []);

  console.log(data);
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <main>
        <div>Welcome to the app</div>
      </main>
    </>
  )
}
```

Error occurring in console:

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED     rustserver-dc:10000/:1

Had the same issue when I was trying to connect two nodes in Kubernetes, and exposing only NextJS app via Nginx reverse proxy

Comment: The web browser can't resolve `rustserver-dc` or connect to it as they are both internal to the docker network. The fetch either needs to be proxied from nginx/localhost to `rustserver-dc:10000` or mapped through the existing `nextjs-app:3000` pathway.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Do you have an idea how to achieve this?
My goal is to achieve that backend & db is not accessible from the browser.

Answer (score 1):

If you want next to fetch the data on the docker network and send it to the client you could use [`getServerSideProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props) to fetch the data when the page is requested, or [`getStaticProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props) to retrieve the data build time.

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const res = await axios.get('http://rustserver-dc:10000')
  return {
    props: res.data, // will be passed to the page component as props
  }
}
```

If you need the client to make requests for `rustserver-dc` outside of those times, you could add an [API route](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction) to next that proxies the request onto the rustserver-dc service.